# How to run a specific junit test in ant with parameter?

Tags: java, junit, ant

First, I have searched in stackoverflow, the following questions are related to mine, but not exactly what I wanted:

- [How to run only specific JUnit tests in Ant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32556060/how-to-run-only-specific-junit-tests-in-ant)
- [How to run JUnit test cases from the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2235276/how-to-run-junit-test-cases-from-the-command-line)
- [Use Ant for running program with command line arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730880/use-ant-for-running-program-with-command-line-arguments)

Suppose I have more than 100 test cases: A1Test... A100Test. I can make `bachtest` of junit in `ant` to run all of them. But I only want to run, say, A50Test. How I config my `build.xml`, so that I can run:

```
ant test A50Test
```

I don't want to create 100 targets for each of the test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Introduce property which defines test name you want to execute:

```
<property name="unit.test" value="*.java" />
```

Use this property in your batchtest:

```
<batchtest fork="yes" todir="${output.test.dir}">
    <fileset dir="${source.test.dir}" includes="**/${unit.test}"/>
</batchtest>
```

Pass value for this property to ant:

```
ant test -Dunit.test=A50Test
```

Answer (score 0):

but in my case, I need to add ".java" at the end of ${unit.test} make it worked.
hope to help someone. ^^

```
<batchtest fork="yes" todir="${output.test.dir}">
    <fileset dir="${source.test.dir}" includes="**/${unit.test}.java"/>
</batchtest>
```